# MySQL subquery for group by fields

Tags: mysql, subquery

I have a MySQL table called sessions, this table has attendance of sessions attended by user_id with the date. I am able to get average attendance percentage by using the following syntax which basically divides total attended sessions by total possible sessions and multiplies it by 100. This gives me the entire average for the given date range.

```
SELECT (
(SELECT count(*) as total FROM sessions ap JOIN session_codes codes USING (code_id) WHERE ap.session_year=2017 AND (ap.session_date BETWEEN '2017-01-15' AND '2017-05-10') AND codes.status>=1) / 
(SELECT count(*) as total_sessions FROM sessions WHERE (session_date BETWEEN '2017-01-15' AND '2017-05-10') AND session_year=2017)
) * 100 AS percentage
```

However, what I would like to do is group the results by user_id and for each user_id run some sort of subquery to look like the above but also have a clause to say where user_id is the one from the loop. That way i can get the percentage for individual users and have the results look something like this:

```
user_id   attendance
1211      89
3344      96
```

does anyone know how this can be achieved?

I ran an explain syntax on the sessions table and this is how my sessions table looks:

```
user_id         bigint(20)   NO    PRI  NULL
session_year    year(4)      NO    PRI  NULL
session_date    date         NO    PRI  NULL
am_pm           bigint(20)   NO    PRI  NULL
code_id         bigint(20)   YES        NULL
user            varchar(50)  YES        NULL
```

Comment: can post the relevant table structure? some people - me included - troubled on how to begin solving your problem without it...

Comment: Agreed with @Bagus Tesa. share table schemas

Comment: @Bagus Tesa how do I post table structure? Its a basic table with session_date, user_id, am_pm, code_id, session_year, user. The first 3 fields have to be unique

Comment: Hi @Ahmed, you could just put an [Entity Relaionship Diagram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity–relationship_model) in ascii-styled (just like how you put sql query there), or take screenshot of your sql table structure.. use [`explain <table_name>`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/explain.html) for instance..

Comment: @Bagus Tesa I ran an explain syntax on the table and updated the post with the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `GROUP BY`, e.g.:

```
SELECT user_id, count(*) as total 
FROM sessions ap JOIN session_codes codes USING (code_id) 
WHERE ap.session_year=2017 AND (ap.session_date BETWEEN '2017-01-15' AND '2017-05-10') AND codes.status>=1
GROUP BY user_id
```

This will give you attendance by user. You can now divide it by total to get the percentage, e.g.:

```
SELECT a.user_id, a.total / (SELECT count(*) as total_sessions FROM sessions WHERE (session_date BETWEEN '2017-01-15' AND '2017-05-10') AND session_year=2017 and user_id = a.user_id)
FROM (
   SELECT user_id, count(*) as total 
   FROM sessions ap JOIN session_codes codes USING (code_id) 
   WHERE ap.session_year=2017 AND (ap.session_date BETWEEN '2017-01-15' AND '2017-05-10') AND codes.status>=1
   GROUP BY user_id
) a;
```

Comment: Seems to be on the right track, but when I run the second code the attendance percentages are completely wrong per user_id. Any ideas whats wrong? My very first example in the post gets attendance percentage for everything so if that same syntax has a ap.user_id= clause and a user_id= clause in the second part then it should give me the correct percentage per user_id

Comment: We need to add `user_id` in `sessions` table's query as well. I have updated the answer, try now?

Comment: that's awesome, is there a way to multiply the result by 100 too in order to get the actual percentage? a 98.45 percent value as 0.9845

Comment: am I correct in placing the *100 at the end of line 1 where user_id = a.user_id) * 100 ? Can I put * 100 AS percentage that way the field name will be percentage?

Comment: Yes, that's fine.